Есть ли в C++ безопасная для хранения паролей строка?
С точки зрения безопасности после того, как пароль перестаёт использоваться программой, его стоит занулять.
То есть хотелось бы иметь какую-нибудь безопасную строку вместо std::string, которая при уничтожении или при присваивании ей нового значения зануляла бы область памяти, в которой хранится старая c-style строка.
Реализовать такую строку самостоятельно - не проблема, но всё-таки на реализацию всех широких возможностей std::string, которые хотелось бы иметь, уйдёт немало времени.
Есть ли уже готовые варианты для такого?

Да, без сомнения, С++ хорош для экономики -- он создает рабочие места

Под винду есть SecureZeroMemory. Не строка, но функция, которая не будет исключена оптимизаторами. Есть вот вопрос на enSO по теме.

Зачем реализовывать "все широкие возможности", если их можно просто наследовать?...

@Harry у наследования есть свои проблемы. Мне не кажется, что basic_string пригоден для наследования, хотя бы потому что его деструктор и другие в данном вопросе методы, такие как clear или operator= не виртуальные. Хотя, возможно, в данном вопросе с этим можно было бы смириться...

Я нашел решение в этом ответе на Stack Overflow (англ).
CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup - это специальный аллокатор, предоставленный библиотекой Crypto++. При деаллокации он зануляет выделенную память.
Деаллокация происходит при уничтожении строки или при переполнении её буфера, что приводит к созданию нового буфера большего размера, в то время как старый буфер освобождается (могут быть и другие сценарии).
Однако это может не сработать при использовании операций clear() или resize().
Мое решение, основанное на том ответе:
SecureString.h
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>

template <typename CharType, typename TraitsType = std::char_traits<CharType>>
using BasicSecureString = std::basic_string<CharType, TraitsType, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<CharType>>;

using SecureString = BasicSecureString<char>;

CMAkeLists.txt
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} cryptopp)

Как установить библиотеку на дистрибутивах, основанных на Ubuntu:
sudo apt install libcrypto++-dev


Проверяли, что напечатает на таком коде: const char* p; {SecureString s = "test"; p = s.c_str();} cout << p;?

@wololo проверил. Очистка не работает. Не знаю, почему.

Small String Optimization. Короткие строки экземпляры класса basic_string хранят внутри себя, память с помощью аллокатора не выделяется.

@wololo плохо..

Для чего вообще может потребоваться string при обработке пароля? imho простого блока памяти (char *) там вполне хватает
